# How to write data to yaml file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to build a simple windows form that is supposed to write values to yaml configuration file.After being published, the exe file is saved in the **config** directory.

```
private void buttonSaveSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hostname = hostnameBox.Text;

    var path = "C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\packages\\doctrine.yaml";
    var deserializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Deserializer();

    try
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            var obj = deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<object, object>>(reader);
            var doctrine = (Dictionary<object, object>)obj["doctrine"];
            var dbal = (Dictionary<object, object>)doctrine["dbal"];
            var connections = (Dictionary<object, object>)dbal["connections"];
            var dict = (Dictionary<object, object>)connections["default"];

            // TODO: Modify the dictionary
            // dict["dbname"] = "test";

            dict["dbname"] = "test";

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                // Save Changes
                var serializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer();
                serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        dumpBox.Text = exception.Message;
    }
}
```

That's the doctrine config file (packages/doctrine.yaml)

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname: dbname
                user: user
                password: password
                host: host
                driver: pdo_mysql
                server_version: '10.0.38-MariaDB'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

I'm not sure if that task could be handled just by using the System.IO, since we may need some additional parser.

The question is, how can I rewrite each key's value that belongs to doctrine/dbal/connections/default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

- First install [YamlDotNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YamlDotNet/)
  (if you use .NET Core `dotnet add package YamlDotNet --version 8.1.2`) or (if you use the package manager `PM> Install-Package YamlDotNet -Version 8.1.2`)

Adapt the code for your needs

```
var path = "/path/to/file.yaml";
var deserializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Deserializer();

try {
    using var reader = new StreamReader(path);
    var obj = deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<object, object>>(reader);
    var doctrine = (Dictionary<object, object>)obj["doctrine"];
    var dbal = (Dictionary<object, object>)doctrine["dbal"];
    var connections = (Dictionary<object, object>)dbal["connections"];
    var dict = (Dictionary<object, object>)connections["default"];
    reader.Close()

    // TODO: Modify the dictionary
    // dict["dbname"] = "test";                    

    using var writer = new StreamWriter(path);
    // Save Changes
    var serializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer();
    serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: manage
}
```

Comment: Great, seems to be a solution! I have to mention that a warning occurs.It says: "The process cannot access the file 'C:\packages\doctrine.yaml' because it is being used by another process".I suppose there is something wrong in the algorithm that should be fixed.What could be the reason?

Comment: It must be a problem with the permissions, try moving the file to another place, or try to open the program as administrator if you are on **Windows**

Comment: I moved it to the desktop with current dir: "C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\packages\\doctrine.yaml" and nothing has changed.Does it work for you?

Comment: yes it works for me but, i am working on linux, you have the file in the current dir of your program?

Comment: I've updated the post so you could see.I'm setting the path in the variable directly.If I may ask, how do you set your path? This could be the problem.Currently, I'm just pointing to its full path just for testing and I suppose it gotta be working as well.

Comment: I am using a path relative to the current directory. [View](https://pasteboard.co/Jd5lBWA.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215957/discussion-between-jorge-alejandro-and-stephan882).

Comment: The problem was that we had to close the reading stream and open the writing one after that.Having applied reader.Close() everything works.

Comment: Of course, I am dumb, I did not realize, it is that since I used the `using (reader var ...)` I forgot it, but since they are nested it does not close it, it seems linux has a better file management so it works there, I am definitely dumb, I am very glad that it worked.

Answer (score -1):

There is already a Yaml Library for .NET project.

```
YamlParser parser = new YamlParser();
TextInput input = new TextInput(File.ReadAllText(yamlFilePath));
bool success;
YamlStream yamlStream = parser.ParseYamlStream(input, out success);
if (success)
{
    foreach (YamlDocument doc in yamlStream.Documents)
    {
        // access DataItem by doc.Root
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(parser.GetEorrorMessages());
}
```

Or:

```
YamlStream yamlStream = YamlParser.Load(yamlFilePath);
```

Incase of any other help please follow http://yaml-net-parser.sourceforge.net/

You can see this fiddle link https://dotnetfiddle.net/rrR2Bb